# IF condition not working with two drop downs in Microsoft PowerApps

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps

So I am trying to make a dynamic branching form in Sharepoint using PowerApps (main reason is Microsoft Forms is extremely buggy when it comes to using branching)

The scenario is that I have **Drop-down A** and **Drop-down 1**, **Drop-down 2** and so on to several drop-downs.

When I select **Drop-down A**, **Drop-down 1** should appear.

For the **Visible** property of **Drop-down 1** I have entered the following code:

```
If(ACD_DataCard1.Selected.Value = "Sample 1",true,false)
```

ACD_DataCard1.Selected.Value = ID of **Drop-down 1**

For some reason it does not work and says the argument is invalid, I have checked different videos on Youtube and some forums as well they all point to the same thing, but still mine does not work.

Any ideas or suggestions would be really great.

Some of the links that I checked out.

[Link 1](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-get-form-questions-to-use-branching-logic/m-p/112565#M40392)

[Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCXT3PyOp4A)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to set the visible property of Drop-down 1 based on the selection of Drop-down A, the visible property of Drop-down 1 should be set as,

```
    If(Drop-downA.SelectedText.Value = "Sample 1",true,false)
```

where Drop-downA is the ID of Drop-down A.